# Does making all fields final of an object guarantees safe publication?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading about safe publication from "Java Concurrency in Practice" and needs help to understand this one example. I know it is simple but looks like i got too much into it and got confused.

```
public class VolatileCachedFactorizer implements Servlet {
private volatile OneValueCache cache =
    new OneValueCache(null, null);

public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
    BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
    BigInteger[] factors = cache.getFactors(i);
    if (factors == null) {
        factors = factor(i);
        cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors);
    }
    encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
}
}

class OneValueCache {
private final BigInteger lastNumber;
private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;

public OneValueCache(BigInteger i,
                     BigInteger[] factors) {
    lastNumber  = i;
    lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
}

public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i) {
    if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i))
        return null;
    else
        return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
}
}
```

Above are the two classes, One is VolatileCachedFactorizer which is a servlet and will be initialized only once by the container and each request would call service method to get the factors of the number passed.

Now, OneValueCache is an immutable object which would cache the latest number in the cache along with its factors.
Now, as per the book it is safely published.

My question is that OneValueCache is not declared final in VolatileCachedFactorizer although all its fields are final. When the constructor of OneValueCache is executed from service method then isn't the following scenario possible - 
lastNumber would be properly initialized (as it is final) but lastFactors is not as both these statements are atomic. So, are there chances that it might be in an improper state.
If OneValueCache was declared final in VolatileCachedFactorizer  then JVM would guarantee that it would be properly initialized.

Thanks

Comment: If a variable is volatile. it is only guaranteed to be visible to all threads (With latest value) but does volatile also guarantees that constructor would be executed properly for a given thread?

Comment: what do you mean by "last factors is not as both these statements are atomic"?

Comment: If all the fields are final and methods that mutate state return a new object, then that object is considered immutable, and is safe to use across multiple threads. Is immutability what you want? Thats another question. (continued in next comment)

Comment: As for the variable holding the immutable object, the variable must be declared final to be safe to use across different threads. Immutability ensures the object cannot change state, but just because an object is immutable does not mean the variable holding the object is safe to use across multiple threads. You should declate it final if possible, as immutable fields are always better than mutable ones, if allowed (check out the book Hardcore Java)

Comment: The perspective in this example is to demonstrate the usefulness of volatile to immediately make available changes to a volatile variable that holds an immutable object. A new cache object is being created on a certain condition and that is the reason for it to be not final.

Comment: Note that in this example, there is no subsequent use of the cache anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your specific question is no. But the thing to note is that the OneValueCache instance "cache" is created in the service method and immediately made visible to all other threads since that is made possible due to the characteristics of the volatile keyword. If thread A writes to a volatile variable then once it is finished then thread B would see all the changes that thread A made if it encounters the volatile variable.

With volatile there are no reordering of memory operations and once the object is created then it is immediately available to be read since the volatile variables are not cached within a local cache wherein it is not visible to other threads on another processor.

If your confusion is on the cache object being properly instantiated then yes, then only the properly constructed immutable cache object be made visible to other threads.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, but i understand what a volatile variable does - no doubts on this. My question is related to object creation (Cache) . Will the object creation be complete? I mean are we certain that if Thread1 starts executing OneValueCache then it will complete the creation and not leave the instance in an unstable state? I feel if OneValueCache is declared final then JVM gurantees that but this is not the case here.

Comment: It does not matter if the object creation is complete when a thread switching happens. Only when it is complete will the other threads see the completed and valid state of the cache instance.

Comment: That exactly was my question :). So If Thread1 initialize cache variable with value say value1  and its factors. After that Thread2 starts with this and gets switched in the constructor and Thread3 gets the chance to run now. So, thread3 will see the cache object written by Thread1 (not the incomplete object Thread2)? Can you please state any references to it. I understand JVM gaurantees this final fields but is it true for volatile as well?

Comment: yes thread3 will see the cache object written by thread1 since the object that was created would in the end be assigned to the variable which is the final step. And the other threads would also see this as the final step and consequently since there is no reordering of steps, they would all see the correct state of the object.